# If I do not enter anything from the console my program does not stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads. The first asks questions, the second checks the answers. If I do not enter anything from the console after 10 questions, then my program does not stop. How to fix it?

```
public void produce() throws InterruptedException {

        for (this.i = 0; this.i < 10; this.i++) {
            if (this.exit) {
                try {
                    this.lock.lock();
                    Bot.LOGGER.info(this.questions.get(this.i));

                } finally {
                    this.lock.unlock();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = "";

        while (this.exit) {
            try {
                if ((!(inputString = scanner.nextLine()).equals(""))) {
                    this.lock.lock();
                    if (inputString.equals(this.answers.get(this.i))) {
                        Bot.LOGGER.info("Correct!");
                        Bot.LOGGER.info("The program was finished");
                        this.exit = false;
                        } 
                    else {
                        Bot.LOGGER.info("Wrong answer!");
                        }
                    } 

            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }
        scanner.close();
        }
```

Comment: Do you ever set `this.exit`?

Comment: How is the `this.i` initialized? Is this loop ever exited?

Comment: this is part of the code.

Comment: this.exit and this.i were initialized

Comment: How do you declare `this.exit`? It should be declared as `volatile`, also looks like your program should exit after first correct answer anyway

Comment: with volatile the same happens. it just doesn't finish.